# GLPK as Solver Factory for Pyomo Python on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, pyomo

I have been struggling for hours to make `GLPK` work with `Pyomo` on Mac OS.
I have tried installing from different sources and using different file paths, but I keep getting the error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgmp.10.dylib
> Referenced from: /opt/anaconda3/pkgs/glpk-4.65/lib/libglpk.40.dylib
> Reason: image not found
> ERROR: Solver (glpk) returned non-zero return code (-6)
> ERROR: See the solver log above for diagnostic information.

This is the path to the `glpsol` executable.

I appreciate any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Do not download GLPK using Conda. It is outdated and won't work. Instead, download the GLPK.5-0.tar directly from the Free Software Foundation website. I make no guarantee that it is a safe file, but it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).